Calculate best possible lineup from a team of players using performance ratings in Libreoffice/Excel

I'm stuck at what I suppose is an optimization problem.
Here my spreadsheet is showing two tables, the one at the top displays the performance ratings of various players at different football positions. The one at the bottom tries to display the best possible team lineup when given a specific team formation (in this case 1 ST, 2 LW/RWs, 2 CMs, 1 CDM, 2 LB/RBs, 2 CBs, and 1 GK). With best possible team lineup, I mean the Player combination that would have the highest possible combined rating when adding each of their performance ratings.
I've tried using the "Goal seek" and "Solver" tools to no avail. They seem to be too limited for what I'm trying to do here. And I've not yet found a set of formulas that solve my problem.
I'm using the latest stable version of Libreoffice ("Goal seek" and "Solver" seem to have the exact same functionality of those tools in Microsoft Office).
Any help would be appreciated.

What if you just looked up the maximum player rating for each position and from there looked up the player who has that max rating for that position?

Hi there, that may be able to work sometimes but not every time. Let's say player 1 has a performance rating of 84 on the CDM position and rating of 83 on the LB/RB position while player 2 has a performance rating of 83 at the CDM position and a 79 rating at the LB/RB position. Now If I were to use Player 1 as a CDM and player 2 as a LB/RB I would get a combined rating of 163 (84+79), while if I where to do the opposite I would get a combined rating of 166 (83+83). So I can't use the player with highest available rating in each position.

As you already suggested, using the Solver can be an option for this. I think then it only depends on the right setup. In principle, I used the same data as you but instead of Player 1, Player 2 etc., I simply named them 1, 2 etc., because then it allows me to use the procedure in a formulaic way. The input data stored in the range A1:P12 looks as follows:




1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15




ST
80.75
76.10
82.51
77.32
71.97
72.73
74.24
72.71
58.63
64.69
30.55
62.27
67.04
75.87
76.21


LW/RW
85.98
83.99
78.39
77.64
78.87
75.09
75.35
72.97
55.57
62.85
28.48
67.80
63.82
74.24
78.39


CF
85.17
82.16
81.01
78.60
78.36
74.84
76.30
73.07
56.13
65.27
30.61
65.70
65.92
76.51
79.21


CAM
86.33
82.81
78.74
79.85
81.93
76.12
77.55
72.64
56.18
68.04
31.65
67.06
66.37
77.33
80.04


LM/RM
85.11
82.95
75.90
78.31
80.47
76.74
76.94
73.59
57.64
65.05
30.61
70.25
65.96
74.99
79.45


CM
80.97
76.02
70.60
81.52
84.34
78.94
80.42
74.33
62.02
74.53
32.51
69.76
71.37
80.60
80.87


CDM
64.44
62.38
52.87
80.50
80.98
82.79
82.14
77.20
77.24
82.10
31.30
74.31
79.07
81.46
76.51


LWB/RWB
68.02
67.67
53.37
77.93
79.26
82.17
79.40
77.86
73.71
73.84
28.32
76.53
74.72
75.98
75.72


LB/RB
64.03
63.20
49.73
77.59
77.14
82.00
78.99
77.60
76.99
75.73
28.01
76.32
76.41
75.41
73.65


CB
54.10
52.50
47.67
78.22
73.43
81.67
80.67
77.32
86.46
84.06
28.71
74.71
82.55
80.31
70.14


GK
14.06
18.70
16.53
18.61
15.98
18.52
18.64
17.42
11.85
11.49
84.28
11.53
19.13
18.52
16.51



The procedure to obtain a solution looks in principle the same as you already have in your screenshot. However, I also added a column "N", which ensures that each player can only be selected once. I put this in range A14:D26:

The formula in cell C15 is the following and is then copied down, which basically ensures (when using the Solver) that each player can only be used once:
=COUNTIF($B$15:$B$25,B15)

To compute the rating, I use a nested XLOOKUP() procedure that returns the rating for a given player/position combination. The formula in cell D15 and then copied down:
=XLOOKUP(B15,$B$1:$P$1,XLOOKUP(A15,$A$2:$A$12,$B$2:$P$12),0)

In cell D26, I compute the SUM of all ratings:
=SUM(D15:D25)

Now the only thing remaining is the proper setup of the Solver. First, we want to maximize the sum of ratings in cell D26, by varying the players in the range B15:B25. This is ultimately the reason for using 1, 2 etc. instead of Player 1, Player 2 etc. The last thing is simply adding some constraints: (i) the players can only take (a) integers and (b) need to be in the range between 1 and 15 (i.e., the number of players). (ii) we set the constraint that each player can only be selected once, for which we use the computations in column C, which needs to be equal to 1 for each of player.

After some iterations, the Solver will find a solution in which all constraints and optimality conditions are satisified. The final results are already presented in the table above.

EDIT: Based on the comment; the issue is that the GRG Nonlinear solver is not guaranteed to find the global minimum. As such, one could switch to the Simplex LP method, which guarantees an optimal solution. The caveat is that the approach is somewhat more restrictive, i.e., all constraints and the objective function have to be linear. Nevertheless, one can reformulate the problem as such using a decision table. The input data remains the same as above in range A1:P12.
Then, we create a table which allows to obtain the values for the actual formation in the range A14:P25. In column A, you simply enter the formation positions, possibly via a drop-down menu. And then we obtain the values for each player using XLOOKUP in cell B15 as follows and then copied to the other cells:
=XLOOKUP(B$14,$B$1:$P$1,XLOOKUP($A15,$A$2:$A$12,$B$2:$P$12),0)

Next, we construct a binary decision table in the range A27:P38. In this context, we also create checks for the players and positions in rows and columns as each can be used only once. For this, we have in cell Q28 and B39 the following formulas and then simply copied to the other rows/columns:
=SUM(B28:P28)
=SUM(B28:B38)

We define the objective function in cell B41 as:
=SUMPRODUCT(B15:P25,B28:P38)

Finally, we set up the Simplex LP solver as follows (i.e., maximize the objective function in cell B41, by changing the decision table and adding the binary constraint as well as that the positions/players can be used only once, respectively):

The final Excel sheet looks as follows:

As can be observed, the result obtained now is 915.59 for this given formation.
Now, changing the formation and re-running the solver, we obtain the following result:

As such, the approach easily scales to all formations as everything is more or less automated once the formation is selected.

Hello, thank you for your reply. I seems that we had very similar ideas. With the help of some folks at reddit I was able to get my issue sorted out. However I wasn't able to make Excel's solver to spit out the actual best team lineup, but Libreoffice Calc had no problem at it. It seems you ran into a similar problem than mine since the best lineup for that particular formation has a combined rating of 915.59.

@lionsop This sounds a lot to me, given that the overall sum when always taking the maximum is just 927. What is the final solution? I would be curious to understand how it is obtained.

Sure! Here's the spreadsheet if you wanna take a look at it! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VvdwLtNqmWNoq_AbK1MOEFtEe8SpGAdOSsUcePv9fs0/edit#gid=5497214

Right now, I'm trying to improve upon my spreadsheet so it's able to give the best possible lineup from 2 or more given formations. But I think I got stuck again.

@lionsop See my extension of the answer to use the Simplex LP solver, which should guarantee an optimal solution.
